# Why didn't they use Google instead of KnowsMore in "Ralph Breaks the Internet"?

Tags: product-placement, ralph-breaks-the-internet

In *Ralph Breaks the Internet*, why don't they use Google instead of KnowsMore as a search engine?

You might say Google didn't sponsor the film, so that they didn't feature it as a search engine. But Google is still there in the movie.

The same question goes for BuzzzTube. There is a YouTube building on the internet, but they still refer BuzzzTube as a major video sharing platform.

If Google didn't sponsor for featuring its search engine and YouTube as the main platforms, why are they still there? Or is the issue that Google didn't sponsor "enough" to get them featured as the main platforms?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**In Universe**, Ralph and Vanellope are totally inexperience internet users.  So it is quite possible that they might use another search engine, such as the fictional KnowsMore instead of Google, and they might use the fictional BuzzzTube instead of YouTube.  It is perfectly possible for new internet users to use the first sites, programs, and services of a type that they find, without previously knowing which is the best, most popular, most famous, or most suitable to their needs.

**Out of universe**, not using Google and YouTube results in not depicting them in a negative or misleading way, while showing that they exist in the internet acknowledges their existence and at least some of their importance.  So perhaps showing that Google and YouTube exist in the internet but not using them was chosen as a middle ground between Scylla and Charybdis.

Comment: Well, in Universe I got your point. Which is relatable to KnowsMore, not BuzzTube. For BuzzTube case they get recommended by Shank

Comment: Out of universe, it still has Ebay don't they?

Comment: @musooff  And perhaps Shank has a specific reason for referring them to BuzzTube instead of YouTube, like getting kickbacks for referrals, or being an investor in BuzzTube, or having had bad experiences with YouTube, etc.,.